# Changing TypeConverter of a 3rd party library type

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, formatting

I have a `Point3D` class in a 3rd party library with its own `TypeConverter` that formats the point as `10,20,30`. I need to change it as `10;20;30` (semicolon in place of the comma).

Is there any way to change how I display it in my application property grids? Is it possible to enforce a different `TypeConverter` in some way?

Maybe a different approach to solve my problem exists?

Answer (score 0):

You can, yes, by hijacking the `PropertyDescriptor` API and providing a custom `TypeDescriptionProvider`. Now, there are a *lot* of moving parts here, but you can cheat and use a "decorator" approach so that you use the original versions for the bits you don't want to change. The following is long - look for `// your custom code here` (there are two of them).

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // connect our custom handling
        MyProvider.Apply();

        // show some conversions using *regular* type descriptor APIs
        var obj = new Point3D(1, 2, 3);
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(obj);
        var s = converter.ConvertToString(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        var clone = converter.ConvertFromString(s);
        Console.WriteLine(clone);
    }
}

// this is the external type - note, the version here is imcomplete
// and doesn't declare a type descriptor etc, but that's fine - the
// important thing is that we don't "fix" this by changing this type
readonly struct Point3D
{
    public Point3D(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }
    public int X { get; }
    public int Y { get; }
    public int Z { get; }
    public override string ToString() => $"X={X}, Y={Y}, Z={Z}";
}
```

with the actual work done in a custom provider:

```cs
public sealed class MyProvider : TypeDescriptionProvider
{
    private readonly TypeDescriptionProvider _tail; 
    public static void Apply()
    {
        var type = typeof(Point3D);
        var tail = TypeDescriptor.GetProvider(type);
        if (tail is MyProvider) return; // already done
        var head = new MyProvider(tail);
        TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(head, type);
    }
    private MyProvider(TypeDescriptionProvider tail) => _tail = tail;

    public override object CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type objectType, Type[] argTypes, object[] args)
        => _tail.CreateInstance(provider, objectType, argTypes, args);
    public override IDictionary GetCache(object instance)
        => _tail.GetCache(instance);
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(object instance)
        => new WrappedTypeDescriptor(_tail.GetExtendedTypeDescriptor(instance));
    public override string GetFullComponentName(object component)
        => _tail.GetFullComponentName(component);
    public override Type GetReflectionType(Type objectType, object instance)
        => _tail.GetReflectionType(objectType, instance);
    public override Type GetRuntimeType(Type reflectionType)
        => _tail.GetRuntimeType(reflectionType);
    public override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type objectType, object instance)
        => new WrappedTypeDescriptor(_tail.GetTypeDescriptor(objectType, instance));
    public override bool IsSupportedType(Type type)
        => _tail.IsSupportedType(type);

    private sealed class WrappedTypeDescriptor : ICustomTypeDescriptor
    {
        private readonly ICustomTypeDescriptor _tail;
        public WrappedTypeDescriptor(ICustomTypeDescriptor tail) => _tail = tail;
        public AttributeCollection GetAttributes() => _tail.GetAttributes();
        public string GetClassName() => _tail.GetClassName();
        public string GetComponentName() => _tail.GetComponentName();
        public TypeConverter GetConverter() => new MyConverter(_tail.GetConverter());
        public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent() => _tail.GetDefaultEvent();
        public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty() => _tail.GetDefaultProperty();
        public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType) => _tail.GetEditor(editorBaseType);
        public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents() => _tail.GetEvents();
        public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes) => _tail.GetEvents(attributes);
        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties() => _tail.GetProperties();
        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes) => _tail.GetProperties(attributes);
        public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd) => _tail.GetPropertyOwner(pd);
    }

    private sealed class MyConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        private readonly TypeConverter _tail;
        public MyConverter(TypeConverter tail)
            => _tail = tail;

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            if (value is string s)
            {
                // your custom code here
                var parts = s.Split(';');
                if (parts.Length == 3)
                {
                    int x = int.Parse(parts[0], culture);
                    int y = int.Parse(parts[1], culture);
                    int z = int.Parse(parts[2], culture);
                    return new Point3D(x, y, z);
                }
            }
            return _tail.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }
        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string) && value is Point3D point)
            {
                // your custom code here
                return string.Format(culture, "{0};{1};{2}", point.X, point.Y, point.Z);
            }
            else
            {
                return _tail.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
            }
        }
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
            => _tail.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
            => _tail.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        public override object CreateInstance(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IDictionary propertyValues)
            => _tail.CreateInstance(context, propertyValues);
        public override bool GetCreateInstanceSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            => _tail.GetCreateInstanceSupported(context);
        public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value, Attribute[] attributes)
            => _tail.GetProperties(context, value, attributes);
        public override bool GetPropertiesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            => _tail.GetPropertiesSupported(context);
        public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            => _tail.GetStandardValues(context);
        public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            => _tail.GetStandardValuesExclusive(context);
        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            => _tail.GetStandardValuesSupported(context);
        public override bool IsValid(ITypeDescriptorContext context, object value)
            => _tail.IsValid(context, value);
    }
}
```